# Character level tokenization with special tokens

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, tokenize, recurrent-neural-network, tf.data.dataset

I am feeding my discord server messages into an RNN, so that i can create a chatbot based on those messages. I know tensorflow's `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` can tokenize on a character level, but I wanted to include special tokens, since I want the bot to simulate a person writing multiple messages on discord pressing enter multiple times for each phrase. An example of a sentence would be, with special tokens:
 `'<START> im a riot <ENTER> ok <ENTER> lets see here <END> '`

How can I include special tokens like this in this situation? So far the only way i've found is to use the regex method `re.findall` to separate characters and special tokens (`re.findall(r'(?:(?:<[\w]+?>)|(?:[\w.,?!:]))`), however, it is slow and I would prefer some sort of tensorflow method to make it portable and to be able to use graph execution on tf.data Datasets.